# How to nudge someone to award a bounty for a correct answer?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I've answered a question, *[External links URL encoding leads to '%3F' and '%3D' on Nginx server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470191/external-links-url-encode-3f-3d-nginx-server/21012310#21012310)*, within a couple of hours after a bounty was started, addressing concerns of both the OP and the person who's running a bounty (who requested official sources — "Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.", a request with which I've complied, by including the original answer for a similar question by an developer of the technology at stake).

However, it would seem like bounty rules prevent awards within 24 hours after the bounty was started. Is that why the bounty was not awarded originally?

Else, there is only a couple of hours left until the expiration of the grace period; is there a way to nudge the person who has offered the bounty to award it, because all matters of the question were addressed?

Comment: I don't think you should force anyone to award a bounty. The notifications I get to my e-mail and on the top-bar from SE is annoying enough, I don't want to have a user beginning to pester me again

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: Most users will just keep the bounty open for the duration.  Or not show up at all, he has not visited the site for a week.  Nudging won't help.

Comment: I would rarely award a bounty till near the end. There can always be a better answer

Comment: @RichardTingle, that could be true in some situations; however, with the grace period being so short, aren't you running the chance of missing the window, and failing to abide by your social contract?

Comment: @cnst Ha! I fear you may be underestimating my addiction to stack overflow (as evidence for this I present my 3 minute reply time)

Comment: @RichardTingle, I have a 2 minute one!

Comment: @cnst But seriously 24 is easily enough time. Awarding the bounty to the first acceptable answer is not the way to maximise quality. Additionally, from a selfish point of view; quite often answers get more rep from the bounty-attention votes than the bounty itself, so its actually in your interests for it not to be awarded yet

Comment: @RichardTingle, that is true, but in this situation, the bounty was actually on someone else's question, so, the extra reputation points wouldn't really fly; plus, it appears, there aren't that many nginx specialists that are visiting stackoverflow, and also my specific answer was already a reference to an answer by an actual developer, so, you can't really get better than that.

Comment: We can leave a comment using `@[name here]` to notify the user with active bounty on a question. I just did it, just be careful not to post "give me the bounty" but be more subtle.

Comment: If you *could* pester someone to award a bounty, and I was the one who had posted the bounty, I'd be really tempted to award it to *anyone else* because you annoyed the heck out of me about it. :-)

Comment: Update: the bounty _just now_ got awarded (to cnst, too!)

Comment: Yes, I see.  Nice. :-)  Any word of what made it happen?  It looked like John has already logged in during the grace period, why did he wait until 2 hours prior to the end of the grace period to award it?  Did someone nudge him?

Answer (score 16):

You don't. Just as you don't push anyone into accepting answers, you don't push them into awarding bounties. It's up to them to decide what to award it to, and when to award it. And if they don't, the system will at least award half of it along criteria [mentioned in this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work). So just be patient and see what happens.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the link in your post is not leading to the correct place.

Comment: @Bart yeah but sometimes the people who start a bounty can act like a-holes by milking as much as possible to they get multiple answers from hungry for point users. I wish there was way to pinpoint that behavior.

Comment: Nobody is forced to answer anything @Rico. And the rep is gone for the OP anyway. Don't really see the problem here.